# Is there a way for two containers in VSCode to communicate from different projects?

Tags: docker, networking, visual-studio-code, containers

I have two different Node.JS Projects I created in VSCode.  On occasion, project A needs to make a call into project B.  Project A is running on port 60100.  Project B is running on port 60200. When i try to call Project B using http://localhost:60200/ I get a transport error.  If i expose port 60200 on both container configs (devcontainer.json) it will throw an error because the port is already in use.

I know i could use a docker-compose and run them in the same project, but they have separate git homes and are standalone most of the time.

Is there anything I can do to make them connected?  Maybe use a docker-compose for each separate, but use the same network name in the compose?  Would that let them communicate?

Comment: Use docker networks to connect the two containers each other: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Comment: you would need to include the other project as part of the devcontainer.json (use docker-compose not the default single container), because you can only have one instance, i.e if you shut down the editor it won't keep the containers running

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have a similar setup (two git folders, two devcontainers, one application needs to access the other over HTTP) and can't get it to work. Not even with an external, shared bridge network. Any clues on what to do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I do (although I use it to get my devcontainer to join a docker-compose network, but the same principles should apply)...

In my devcontainer.json...

```json
    "initializeCommand": "docker network inspect my_shared_network > /dev/null || docker network create my_shared_network --attachable",

    "runArgs": [
        "--network=my_shared_network",
    ],
```

This creates a named network if it's not there already, and instructs VSCode to use it for the devcontainer.

You may want to add, e.g., `"--hostname=devcontainer-project-b"` to the runArgs so that you can use that name in your URL.

Answer (score 1):

*Project A* may call other project (*Project B*) running in different VSCode:

`http://workspace:60200`

```json
// Project B .devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Go",
    "service": "workspace", // <-- workspace is in this example, but could be any other value
...
```

This `workspace` (as example) is actual *network alias* visible from:

```bash
docker inspect project_B_devcontainer_workspace_1
```

or using VSCode *Remote explorer* in *Activity Bar* -> *inspect* option of container...